# Get data from link shared from other apps?

Tags: android

We all are very familiar with the ***Copy link***  option within *Share* option in *YouTube* app. When we paste this in *Facebook* or *WhatsApp* its converted to link with details such as title, thumbnail, content . Am looking forward to implement this in my app. But I couldn't find anything relevent.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library:
https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview

**Instantiating**

```
import com.leocardz.link.preview.library.TextCrawler;
// ...
// Create an instance of the TextCrawler to parse your url into a preview.
TextCrawler textCrawler = new TextCrawler();

// ..

// Create the callbacks to handle pre and post exicution of the preview generation.
LinkPreviewCallback linkPreviewCallback = new LinkPreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPre() {
        // Any work that needs to be done before generating the preview. Usually inflate 
        // your custom preview layout here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPos(SourceContent sourceContent, boolean b) {
        // Populate your preview layout with the results of sourceContent.
    }
};
```

**Generate Preview**

```
textCrawler.makePreview( linkPreviewCallback, url);
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response. Can we use this for all links shared or only for youtube link

Comment: Hopefully yes. Still test it first. Also select my answer as "Accepted" if it works for you.